# Add custom template in footer in magento2

Tags: theme, magento2.2.2, custom-template, php-7.2

I have added the custom template in footer. It displayed in all page .But in view page its throwing

```
     1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::html/footer/trustworthy.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'trust.shy'
```

**In default.xml:**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="trust.shy" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/trustworthy.phtml" after="subscribe.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Added template in following path /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/OX/shy/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer/trustworthy.phtml**

If any thing i want to change it ...

thanks.

Comment: Check your theme is `OX/shy` and do the cache flush properly

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="trust.shy" template="html/footer/trustworthy.phtml" after="subscribe.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

> Make sure to re-deploy static view files or better to run upgrade then run deploy static view files.

Comment: Yes.. i have tried all this ... but still its throwing error.